# Alineación de TextView no se respeta al mostrar el item en ListView

Tags: android-studio, android-layout, textview

en el diseñador de mi layout el TextView **Presione para más información** se muestra correctamente, pero cuando ejecuto la APP el ListView lo muestra de manera distinta y no me esta respetando lo que estructure en el layout. ¿A qué se puede deber este inconveniente en el diseño?

Esta es la captura de pantalla de mi diseño del layout y a continuación el como se visualiza en la APP ya compilada.

[image: Diseño del layout]

[image: Vista en la APP]

A continuación les muestro el xml de mi layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="96dip"
    android:background="@color/colorTextMenu"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
    android:elevation="5dp">

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_width="96dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_img_item"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dip">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_atractivo"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="96dip"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/n_atractivo"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        style="@style/TituloItem"
        android:text="Item"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dip"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="0dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/n_atractivo">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            style="@style/DescripcionItem"
            android:text="Presione para más información"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@color/colorBlue"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/id_atractivo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Gracias.

Comment: Lo que puede estar ocasionando el error es el valor `fill_parent` que utilizas en diferentes etiquetas. Prueba cambiando ese valor por el valor `match_parent`

Comment: ya lo intente pero sigue apareciendo igual que en la captura de pantalla

Comment: Es raro, cuando lo pruebo a mi no me da ese error. Lo único que le modifique al xml es la propiedad style de las etiquetas (la elimine). Prueba eliminando esa propiedad, para saber si el problema lo provocan los estilos que definiste para la aplicación. 

También seria bueno que mostraras el código de los estilos que utilizas en las etiquetas..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En lugar de `android:gravity="bottom"` en tu TextView podrias usar `layout_alignParentBottom="true"` o algo equivalente y modificarlo con `layout_marginBottom="10dp"` o como se ajuste mejor, por ejemplo:

```
        <TextView
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
           android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
           android:textStyle="bold"
           style="@style/DescripcionItem"
           android:text="Presione para más información"
           android:textAllCaps="false"
           android:textColor="@color/colorBlue"/>
           <!--android:gravity="bottom"-->
```

Comment: gracias, quedo resuelto el detalle